# Transactions with my contract are older than the contract itself

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-deployment, addresses

I have recently started my blockchain development journey and I can't seem to find an answer to my question.

I have deployed a new contract (the same way as I did a few before) on 19.09.2022 13:25 yet when I check it on [etherscan](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3) it shows a few older transactions as early as 18.09. There are also a lot of transactions from other addresses than mine which I know is possible but I find it odd.

Does anyone know how is that possible or could maybe link me an article to understand why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: According to Etherscan, this is an address, not a contract. Are you sure you described this issue properly?

Comment: Isn't it an address to a contract?

Comment: Oh I know what you meant now.. Yes it indeed is just an address.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I'm dumb and forgot to add the --network param to the hardhat command so it didn't actually deploy anything and just returned my own address I guess? That answered my questions.